# modify xml node value or attribute value with xsl without specifying

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a project which modifies xml documents. I want to modify either a node value or an attribute value. I was able to do that if I specify that it's a node or an attribute value that I want to modify.
Modifying node value in xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="XPath/text()">newValue</xsl:template>
```

Modifying attribute value in xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="XPath">
  <xsl:attribute name="attributeName">newValue</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But I want to modify the values without specifying that it is a node or an attribute. For example here is a short xml:

```
<example>
  <test>
    <node attrName="oldAttrValue">
      oldNodeValue
    </node>
  </test>
</example>
```

I would like to modify the "attrName" attribute value or the "node" node value without specifying which. Is this somehow possible, maybe from an XPath?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't say which node you want to be modified, how is the system to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to modify the "attrName" attribute value or the "node"
>   node value without specifying which. Is this somehow possible

If I understand your question correctly (which is not at all certain) the answer is no.

Keep in mind that the text contained in an **element** is a *node* of its own<sup>1</sup>, and as such can be selected by an XPath expression or matched by a template's match pattern. An **attribute** is a *node*, too - but the value of an attribute is not - and therefore it cannot be selected or matched on its own.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model

--
(1) More precisely: each span of text contained by an element is a separately addressable *node*.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) templates. Basically, they iterate over and copy every element in your xml (elements and attributes alike). Use this, and then either use `template match="..."` or `if` conditional blocks to modify your xml as required. For example:

#### Source XML

```
<example>
  <test>
    <node attrName="oldAttrValue">oldNodeValue</node>
    <node attrName="dontModify1">dontModify2</node>
  </test>
</example>
```

#### XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- modify specific text() nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[.='oldNodeValue']">
    <xsl:text>newElementValue</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- modify specific attribute nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*[.='oldAttrValue']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">newAttributeValue</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output XML

```
<example>
  <test>
    <node attrname="newAttributeValue">newElementValue</node>
    <node attrname="dontModify1">dontModify2</node>
  </test>
</example>
```

If you don't want to specify which attribute/element values to match (i.e. you want to apply the transformation to ALL attribute/element values with non-blank values), simpy replace the `text()[.='oldNodeValue']` and `@*[.='oldAttrValue']` matches with `text()[normalize-space(.)!='']` and `@*[normalize-space(.)!='']` respectively.